# How to remove page title from refinery home page [RAILS]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refinerycms

I'm currently working on a project which I'm building on top of 'refinery cms', I ran in to a problem that in my home page, apart from the page content I added, it shows the page name as 'home',

And I have found out that it returns this from

```
#app/views/refinery/_content_page.html.erb

<%= render_content_page(@page, {
      :hide_sections => local_assigns[:hide_sections],
      :can_use_fallback => !local_assigns[:show_empty_sections] && !local_assigns[:remove_automatic_sections]
    }) %>
```

can someone tell me how to get rid on this page name from the home page

I'm running on

- gem 'refinerycms', '~> 2.0.0'
- gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
- ruby 1.9.2

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6):

Try replacing it with:

```
<%= render_content_page(@page, {
      :hide_sections => [:body_content_title, local_assigns[:hide_sections]],
      :can_use_fallback => !local_assigns[:show_empty_sections] && !local_assigns[:remove_automatic_sections]
    }) %>
```

Comment: If only the title has to be gone: `<%= render '/refinery/content_page', :hide_sections => [:body_content_title] %>`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to look into the render_content_page method?
Maybe it has a specific condition when it renders 'home' name of the page?

Comment: Hi @novotarq, thanks for the quick reply, yes I did (http://rubydoc.info/github/resolve/refinerycms/Refinery/Pages/ContentPagesHelper#render_content_page-instance_method), but coudnt find anything useful ;(

Comment: All I have found is that it populates the first page with 'home' slug and 'Home' title in seeds.rb. Maybe you can manually change that and change your seeds file to your own needs for future use?